# Android - stay on notification list

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm building an Android app which creates notifications.  Each notification has a number of additional actions.

The default application (when the user taps on the notification) launches an activity in my app.  That's working fine.

When the user swipes the notification to dismiss the notification, my app responds by doing some deletion work, and the user is left on the list of notifications.  The one that the user swiped is removed from the list.

For some of my additional actions I want to launch activities, and that's working fine; for the other actions, I want my app to do some work but I also want the user to remain on the notification list.  I'm struggling to find a way to do this last part - all my attempts to configure the intent and pending intent for my additional action result in behaviour whereby when the user clicks on the action, the notification list disappears.

Is there any way to get what I want (i.e. a notification additional action which performs work but leaves the user on the notification list)?  Do I need to build a custom notification layout or something?

Comment: do you want to stop drawer from closing or want to keep notification on drawer?

Comment: I want to stop the drawer from closing.  It so happens that my actions will result in the notification being removed from the drawer (but each different action results in the removal for a different reason - the user can deal with the notification in a variety of ways, according to which action the user chose).

Once the user has dealt with on notification, I want the user to be able to deal with other notifications from my app without having to re-open the notification draw.  (Perhaps I should have said earlier - my app raises multiple notifications.)